# If a variable gets set to the name of a variable, then can it become that variable? (Batch)

Tags: batch-file, optimization

All the P(numbers) are paths. For example, %P1% might be D:\ . Then, I get them to say a number. If they choose 1, I combine that with a P. That gives P1, the first variable. Can I set A to the variable P1? It would make the code way more optimized. I want to try and fit everything in a ridiculously tiny amount of space.
Download: https://mega.nz/file/QYZA3RbQ#Uvr9acXEBssYdXSHkdas1OjFt0X6xdmyl1WLH9HbmP8

````
echo 1.  %P1%
echo 2.  %P2%
echo 3.  %P3%
echo 4.  %P4%
echo 5.  %P5%
set /p Pc=

set "a=p%pc%"
echo %a%
pause```
````

Comment: If you want variable `a` to contain the *name* of another variable (like `p1`), you need to change `echo %a%` to `call echo %%%a%%%` or `echo !%a%!` when [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled (preferred). If you want variable `a` to contain the *value* of another variable, change `set "a=p%pc%"` to `call set "a=%%p%pc%%%"` or `set "a=!p%pc%!` (also with delayed expansion)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, based on the initial code:
Using `delayedexpansion`

```
set "a=!P%Pc%!"
echo %a%
```

or use call

```
call set "a=%%P%Pc%%%"
echo %a%
```

However. to do this right, You will need to change the way your config file works.
For now, your config has a major flaw, you explicitly want to ignore certain line numbers, which if someone removes or add a line, it will break your code. You need to use some for loops and then skip lines that starts with `REM`

So the config needs to look something like this (I made it smaller for the sake of a shorter answer):

```
REM Please set this to 1, or the program will NOT run!
1
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Please put paths to the folder your [PWADS] are in. Not the pwads themselves.
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
pwads=C:\Some path
pwads=D:\Another
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Please put the path to your [IWADS]. Only ten though! Make sure it's the iwads themselves.
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
iwads=D:\iwads1
iwads=D:\some path2
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Please put the path to your [Source Port] exe's. You must be doing something weird if you have more than ten.
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sp=D:\
sp=E:\
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Now, please leave this alone. It's so I know everything works.
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1
```

Now the code. portion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set pwnum=0
set iwnum=0
set spnum=0
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('type launcherconfiguration.txt ^| findstr /v "REM "') do (
    if "%%i" equ "0" (
         echo not configured
         goto :eof
    )
    if "%%~i" == "pwads" (
        set /a pwnum+=1
        set "PWADlocat!pwnum!=%%~j"
      ) else (
    if "%%~i" == "iwads" (
        set /a iwnum+=1
        set "IWADlocat!iwnum!=%%~j"
      ) else (
    if "%%~i" == "sp" (
            set /a spnum+=1
            set "SPlocat!spnum!=%%~j"
    )
   )
  )
 )
echo PWADLocation:
for /l %%a in (1,1,%pwnum%) do echo %%a. !PWADLocat%%a!
set /p pw=Choose:
call echo you chose %%PWADlocat!pw!%%
call set "PW=%%PWADlocat!sp!%%"
echo you chose %PW%
pushd "%PW%" rem This will goto the dir
rem do other things
popd

echo IWADLocation:
for /l %%a in (1,1,%iwnum%) do echo %%a. !IWADLocat%%a!
set /p pw=Choose:
call set "IW=%%IWADlocat!sp!%%"
echo you chose %IW%
pushd "%IW%" rem This will goto chosen the dir
rem do other things
popd

echo SPLocation:
for /l %%a in (1,1,%spnum%) do echo %%a. !SPLocat%%a!
set /p sp=Choose:
call set "SP=%%SPlocat!sp!%%"
echo you chose %SP%
pushd "%SP%" rem This will goto the chosen SP dir
rem do other things
popd
```

So let me explain it briefly. We set a number per datatype, we simply increase the count as more lines matched are found and then we use another `for /l` loop to just use the count again.

To test this, you need to copy this code into a new batch file, place it in the same location as your config file and test it. There are alot more to your code, but I have only focused on what you asked.

Note, I would still prefer to use `choice` but because of the beeping you mentioned, I retained the `set /p` option in this code.

Comment: Any way to stop it from beeping?

Comment: that is a warning that you chose the wrong key. The instruction is clear, 5 options, don't use another :)  but it can be set to not beep, but it will be per system. You are welcome to use you `set /p` still if you like, I just gave you choice, because that it is a better way to use choices.

Comment: I only get "ECHO is off" using set /p. I'm releasing it to public so I don't want to make a large annoying sound.

Comment: showing only echo off means you're setting something wrong, edit your question and show the full code, including how you `set` the `Pn` variables.

Comment: you are not showing how you set the variables. somewhere must be `set "P1=something"` etc..

Comment: no, that won't work. let me update answer, but I need you to show me the config file content bu [`editing`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67145655/edit) your question